# Unable to evaluate the expression Cannot find source class for java.util.List

Tags: retrofit

I response this error when get JSON data by retrofit.

```java
List<NewLicense> result = null;
Call<List<NewLicense>> serviceResult = ShahrdariApp.getShahrdariWebService().getLicenses(Configuration.getInstance().getString(SharedPrefs.MAC_ADDRESS), id);

try {
    Response<List<NewLicense>> response = serviceResult.execute();
    result = response.body();
    Log.d("responseCode", String.valueOf(response.code()) );

} catch (Exception e) {
    exceptionHandling(e);
    Log.d("responseCode", String.valueOf(e.getMessage()) );
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 18):

Simply restarting the IDE via `File` -> `Invalidate caches` can often solve this issue.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue and forgot to set the Project SDK added this and it resolved the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I faced the message

> Unable to evaluate the expression Cannot find source class for
> java.util.List

in hovering a List field while debugging in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.3 (UltimateEdition).

Even though an SDK was assigned to my Project, it helped to visit
IDEA ->File ->Project Structure -> Platform Settings ->SDKs and re-assign the SDK already visible in the list.
Namely I assigned openjdk-1.8.0.302-1, applied "OK", after that it was possible to debug a List foo.

IDE restart after that may additionally be necessary.